# Combine and sort lists, when order within original lists conserved

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have several datasets which I'm trying to combine and then sort by a certain category, but the order of the original lists needs to be conserved. For instance I have the following data sets:

```
[Event, variable X]

List A -- List B -- List C

[1A, 5] -- [1B, 2] -- [1C, 20]

[2A, 6] -- [2B, 4] -- [2C, 10]

[3A, 2] -- [3B, 12] -- [3C, 14]
```

I want to combine all the sets and see how they rank overall in order of X, which would be simple enough, but the order from their original list needs to be conserved (e.g. 3C can only happen after 2C). So the final list would look like:

```
1. [1B, 2]
2. [2B, 4]
3. [1A, 6]
4. [2A, 5]
5. [3A, 2]
6. [3B, 12]
7. [1C, 20]
8. [2C, 10]
9. [3C, 14]
```

So even though X in 3A is equivalent to 1B and lower than 2B, it can only be listed after all previous "A" events, which themselves cannot be listed until they exceed 2B

Comment: Does the data in that example represent your true data? Is "[1A, 5]" a string which is contained within a single cell? If it is, and assuming that cell to be A1, does that mean that cell A2 contains "[2A, 6]"? In your example, all three lists contain precisely the same number of entries. I assume that this will always be the case (otherwise you would surely not have made your example so "perfect")?

Comment: My data is closer to a several amortization tables, where I have a single funding source and want to optimize the order of payments across all the tables based on a separate variable associated with each payment. The "A", "B" system doesn't actually mean anything, I was just trying to denote which dataset each came from. In reality they're just numbered lists, all with the same number of entries

Comment: In that case, perhaps an example dataset which DOES match your actual one would be of use? I say that as any solution might be dependent on the specifics of the strings involved, so generalized, "dummy" data may actually be counterproductive here.

Comment: Sure, [here's](https://www.sendspace.com/file/fk5y4b) a subset of the data

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to use a named range and Microsoft Query. The problem is that this is not dynamic (if you have 15 columns, you would need to have 15 union statements). If you have thousands of rows, however, it would probably be faster to go my way. If you just have the information in the file or only a few more records, just copy and paste.

1. Name the range of values 'DataRange'
2. Create a new sheet name 'NewTable'
3. Save the file to your desktop/wherever
4. Data > From Other Sources > From Microsoft Query
5. Choose your 'DataRange' named range
6. For each column that you need, put in the following

`SELECT DataRange.ID & 'A',DataRange.'Dataset A' FROM DataRange DataRange 
UNION 
SELECT DataRange.ID & 'B',DataRange.'Dataset B' FROM DataRange DataRange ...`

I think that you follow but let me know.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I follow. I am able to transfer the data to the new sheet using Query, but it's just a wizard that appears and I don't see anywhere to enter the union statements. What is the final result of this process though? I'm not familiar with Query, so I don't immediately see how I'd be able to sort the data using the method I described above

Comment: You have to close the wizard, then click the SQL button, then type in the code above. The final result will be a two column table in a similar format to the table in your example.

Comment: Ahh, I see now, thanks for clarifying. I followed the procedure, but the output only sorts by overall value, and doesn't conserve the order from the original datasets. I added a sheet to the original datasets I linked above ([download new version here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/yo2rch)), which show the output of the MS Query versus the method of sorting I'm targeting. Thanks for your help!